# Help me understand the QThread usage

Tags: qt, qthread

I have the `MainWindow w` windows and `TestThread testThread` as a member of `w`. I know it i simple, but I cannot run the `testThread.foo()` method in `testThread` thread (not in window thread). In another words: I don't understand the QThread behavior.

Please help correct the next test application. There is a `QProgressBar *MainWindow::ui::progressBar` and `QPushButton *MainWindow::ui::startButton` (write simply). I want to start (by `startButton` click) `TestThread::foo(int* progress)` which will increment `int progress` each second.

MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : // ...
{
    // ...

    ui->progressBar->setRange(0, 5);
    progress = 0; // int MainWindow::progress

    this->connect(ui->startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(startFoo()));

    connect(this, SIGNAL(startFooSignal(int*)), &testThread, SLOT(foo(int*)));
        // TestThread MainWindow::testThread

    testThread.start();
}

// ...

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    ui->progressBar->setValue(progress);
}

void MainWindow::startFoo() // this is a MainWindow SLOT
{
    startTimer(100);
    emit startFooSignal(&progress);
        // startFooSignal(int*) is a MainWindows SIGNAL
}
```

TestThread:

```
void TestThread::foo(int *progress) // this is a TestThread SLOT
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        ++*progress; // increment MainWindow::progress
    }
}
```

I know, this is simple. I am doing something wrong :)

**P.S.** I want to run the simpliest (as possible) example to understand the `QThread` behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Small side issue, be aware that updating the progress variable like you do is not thread safe. It often works reasonably well in such as  simple case as yours, but for more precise requirements or complex update patterns, look into using a mutex/critical section or atomic updates. (That helps the data being consistent across threads...)

Comment: @Macke: Thanks, I know that :) I am new to Qt threads class `QThread` and just want to run the simpliest example :) Cannot understand its usage :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical issue  is to have the object containing the `foo()`-function be owned by that thread, so that slot calls are dispatched from the right thread's event-loop.

*(Note that there's no need to actually have `foo()` on the `TestThread` object. You can use  separate objects for `QThread` and `WhatEver::foo()` function. It might be easier too, I'm not sure..)*

IIUC, this is what you have to do:

- Use [QObject::moveToThread()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#moveToThread) to assign the object containing the foo-function to TestThread (that means that `Qt::AutoConenction` (the default) signal/slots calls will run correctly across thread, being dispatched from each thread's own event loop).

By having the object "owned" by the right thread, slots calls will be scheduled on that thread's event loop, rather than executed directly.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I thought there is a default implementation of `run()` where simply the `exec()` is called. And there is no `QObject::pushToThread()` in Qt 4.7 :( Do you use different qt version?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `moveToThread()`: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#moveToThread .. Also, you're right about `run()`  calling `exec()` by default. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Super! It works the way you have described. Many thanks, Macke!! :)

Answer (score 2):

One alternative solution: If you just want to run a function in another thread, and don't insist using QThread, you should check out the [QT Concurrent Namespace.](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/threads-qtconcurrent.html)

The following example will run the function foo() in separate thread and will not block on the line where calling the function. Of course there are mechanisms to understand when a function ends, to get a result, to wait for it, to control execution.

```
void foo(int &progress) {...}

int progress;
QtConcurrent::run(foo, progress);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for this solution (will keep in mind). But I want to use Qt native signals-slots meсhanism to call different slots of `testThread`.

Answer (score 1):

See [QThread::start](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html#start) and [QThread::run](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html#run).

Comment: I have forgotten them in this example, thanks. But what changes should I do to make `foo()` run in a separate thread?

Comment: As I understand, default implementation of `run()` simply calls `exec()` (i.e. the event loop). In my real code I want to call slots of `testThread`. `start` is called e.g. in `MainWindow` constructor.

Comment: Hi, I had problems understanding QThread, too. At the time I made a [test project](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B9PGUhmmnsm1ZDE2NDRiYTgtYTExMy00ZjNiLWI5NTItOTkzYTdjYzBiZjVi&hl=en&authkey=CMzDqfAM) to test those things.